# IMAP connect issue

Tags: imap

I am using IMAP client from this link [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx?fid=91819&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2865930&fr=1#xx0xx].

When I to connect to server, the response is coming something like, "220 Mail.servername.co.in Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.1830 ready at  Fri, 6 Nov 2009 11:41:54 +0530 11/6/2009 11:41:54 AM". I think I should get "* OK".
Plz help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, you are connecting to the SMTP service (probably port 25). You need to connect to the IMAP port (usually 143).